# RavenDb, Query on properties of abstacts class implementations

Tags: c#, ravendb, nosql

I have 3 objects Vehicle, Car and MotorCycle. Vehicle is the abstract base class for Car and MotorCycle.

```
public abstract class Vehicle
{
    public String Color {get;set};
    public Int Price {get;set};
    public DateTime ReleaseDate {get;set};
}

public class Car : Vehicle
{
    public Int EnginePower {get;set};
    public Int TrunkSpace {get;set};
    public bool GearBoxType {get;set};
    public Int Seats {get;set};
}

public class MotorCycle : Vehicle
{
    public Int EnginePower {get;set};
    public String Type{get;set};
}
```

I want to stock all the Vehicles (Cars, motorcycles...) in the same collection of documents in RavenDb. So I am using this convention and it works :

```
documentStore.Conventions.FindTypeTagName =
   type => type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Vehicle)) ?
       DocumentConvention.DefaultTypeTagName(typeof(Vehicle)) :
       DocumentConvention.DefaultTypeTagName(type);
```

Now I want to do indexs for my requests for all vehicles. But i want to request on Vehicle properties and on implementations (Car, MotorCycle) properties.

Examples of requests i would :

- All vehicles with Color="red", EnginePower>100
- All vehicles with Color="red", EnginePower>100, Seats=5
- All vehicles with Type="Scooter"
- etc....

And the result in only one collection of Vehicule type, order by RealeaseDate.
How to do a query like that in C# and linq ?

Answer (score 1):

RavenDB will save the entities as their deriving types and build any automatic index based on those types.

What you need to do is create a new index that indexes the properties in the base class across all the different types and then select from that index.

```
public class VehicleIndex : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask
{
public VehicleIndex()
{
 this.AddMap<Car>(vehicle => from v in vehicle select new { v.Price , v.Color , v.ReleaseDate });
 this.AddMap<Motorcycle>(vehicle => from v in vehicle select new { v.Price , v.Color , v.ReleaseDate });
}
}
```

I have written a more in depth blog post about this using interfaces but exactly the same technique works for abstract base classes. See [blog post here](http://www.lobsterfs.co.uk/blog/ravendb-interface/)

It is actually a very powerful technique and allows you to fully leverage the schema-less nature of Raven.

Comment: Just a quick note, if you want to query by EnginePower you will need to move the property to the base class and include it in the index.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but i don't want to move the Property EnginePower. I can query children classes properties from RavenDb studio in my single collection of documents (multiples types). It is not possible to do that in C# ?

Comment: Then you need to use an interface and build the index off that. The thing to remember in RavenDB is everything is an index, you never really "query" it like a database.

Comment: Is the only solution to create an index with all the properties of implementations of abstracts classes ? (properties of both MotorCycle and Car) ? As a consequence, these properties will be often null...

Answer (score 1):

I came across this thread and would like to correct the comments / answer posted here so far.

It **is** possible to create an index of all inheritances.

Generally speaking, it is best to save all your inheritances in seperate collections. So, in other words, to not save Car as a Vehicle in Raven, but as a Car.

You can then use a `MultiMapIndex` to query on similarities between the different inheritances, but also retain the option to create a seperate index for a specific inheritance, should the need arise.

To get the result you need, simply save the results as a new type wherein you include all properties you want to index (or even create new ones based on input of the child classes)

```
public class VehicleIndex : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask
{
    public class Mapping
    {
        public string Price { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public string ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public int?  EnginePower { get; set;}
    }

    public VehicleIndex()
    {
        this.AddMap<Car>(vehicle => from v in vehicle select new Mapping()
        {
            Price = v.Price,
            Color = v.Color,
            ReleaseDate = v.ReleaseDate,
            EnginePower = v.EnginePower
        });
        this.AddMap<Motorcycle>(vehicle => from v in vehicle select new Mapping()
        {
            Price = v.Price,
            Color = v.Color,
            ReleaseDate = v.ReleaseDate,
            EnginePower = v.EnginePower
        });
    }
}
```

I saved EnginePower as an `int?` so you can add childs to this class that do not have EnginePower and store them as `null`. This allows you to filter on motorcycles and cars by doing `where(a => a.EnginePower.HasValue && (a.EnginePower > 50 || a.EnginePower < 100))`

EDIT: I have since added a custom overload that simply scans the whole solution for classes deriving from T, and adding them to the index as a new map. This means that if a new child gets added, you don't have to manually add them to index definition but simply recompile your indexes and you're good to go.

```
public void AddMapForPolymorphic<TBase>(Expression<Func<IEnumerable<TBase>, IEnumerable>> expr)
    {
        AddMap(expr);
        var children = Modules.Modules.Instance.GetModules()
            .SelectMany(a => AssemblyHelper.GetClassesWithBaseType<TBase>(a.GetType().Assembly)
            );

        var addMapGeneric = GetType()
            .GetMethod("AddMap", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        foreach (var child in children)
        {
            if (!child.HasAttribute<IgnorePolymorpAttribute>())
            {
                var genericEnumerable = typeof(IEnumerable<>)
                    .MakeGenericType(child);

                var delegateType = typeof(Func<,>)
                    .MakeGenericType(genericEnumerable, typeof(IEnumerable));

                var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(delegateType, expr.Body, Expression
                    .Parameter(genericEnumerable, expr.Parameters[0].Name));

                addMapGeneric
                    .MakeGenericMethod(child).Invoke(this, new[] { lambdaExpression });
            }
        }
    }
```